# PHP highcharts not displaying in PDF with dompdf

Tags: php, mysql, dompdf

I have generated a graph, tables using PHP, Mysql and High charts(for graphs), so that I wanted to print all my graphs in to PDF file using DOMPDF, but not able to, is there any issue to display PHP variables?

```
require_once('dompdf/autoload.inc.php');
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->load_html($slide1);//I'm using this variable to store my result
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->output();
$dompdf->stream('test',Array('Attachment'=> 0));
```

Comment: Funny that DomPDF doesn't automagically execute the highcharts javascript to create the chart image; or do you expect the js itself to be embedded in the pdf so that it executes whenever anybody views that?

Comment: May be that helps...is there anyway? or any other better library?

Comment: You can embed static images (such as a png) in a pdf, and that will work with DomPDF as well.... [4 different ways to save a Highcharts chart as a PNG (with and without a server)](https://gist.github.com/philfreo/0a4d899de4257e08a000)